# Why "for loop" is not returning all values in the array when it is not used with addition assignment? What is the workflow behind this?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am a beginner. Please give me an insight into these examples and differentiate the two workflows.

Example 1

```
var arrayList = ["php", "javascript", "c++", "C lang", "Python"];
var text ='';

for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)
{
  text += arrayList[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=text;
```

Example 2

```
var arrayList = ["php", "javascript", "c++", "C lang", "Python"];

 for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)
  {
    var  text = arrayList[i] + "<br>";
   }
 document.getElementById("para").innerHTML=text;
```

Comment: In the first example each string inside the array gets added to the string text. In the second example the string text gets overwritten every time so only the last string from the array will be shown.

Comment: Why downvote? Discourraging ppl?  I said I am not an expert. Give me some space. I believe this is the place I can get and share some knowledge. Don't expect someone to be your level. Everybody is different. Even I don't have prior knowledge.

Comment: @MithunJack Don't worry about the downvotes. They are okay for a newbie... Don't worry... `:)`

Comment: @MithunJack Oru vaati [tour] poi paarunga... `:)`

Comment: @MithunJack Stack Overflow has been bad to newbies and the team is taking effort to make people understand that and refrain from throwing stones. It will get better soon. Meanwhile just have a look at [ask] and [tour] and definitely, there's a lot of improvement that can be done with the question you have asked.

Comment: Thank you  Praveen Kumar Purushothaman. You're the only saving grace today. You sorted out my confusion. Thank you once again for that. Have a nice day.. T

Comment: Brother tamil ah neenga..semma :)

Comment: @MithunJack And one more thing. Please please search the site before asking a question like this. It's very broad and basic... `:(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why this is unclear for you. In the first example, you are clearly **appending** to the `text` variable.

```
text += arrayList[i] + "<br>";
```

You see the `+=` operator? It's called concatenate or append. i.e., it's equivalent to:

```
text = text + arrayList[i] + "<br>";
```

While in your second example, you are just redefining the variable again and again until it gets deleted and has only the last value. You are **over-writing** the variable in the below code.

```
var text = arrayList[i] + "<br>";
```

So you get only one value at the end. It is not about the `var` keyword but the operator you are using. Technically, the only difference between the above two is the operator - one is **assignment** while other is **appending**.

I can give you a better difference between the two using snippets:

**Example 1**

```js
var arrayList = ["php", "javascript", "c++", "C lang", "Python"];
var text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
  text += arrayList[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="para"></div>
```

**Example 2**

```js
var arrayList = ["php", "javascript", "c++", "C lang", "Python"];
var text = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
  text = arrayList[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="para"></div>
```

The second example has been modified to understand the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you gradually append to the `text` variable - something is added to it each time the loop code repeats. At the end you have a string containing all the values from the list.

In the second example the `text` value is  overwritten each time the loop repeats.

---

The key differences are the location where `var text` is declared and the `+=` (to append to a string) rather than `=` (to simply set the variable, disregarding the previous value (if any)).

This is not a particularly complicated example. If you study some of the fairly basic details of JavaScript syntax, the operators and the concept of variable scope then it will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The plus or addition (`+`) operator when used with strings, it concatenates the values together returning a new one that's the union of values.

You can check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String#String_operators

So, in the first example, you go for each item from the array and concatenates each value to a string called `text` and insert this list to the html.

In the second example, you for each item from the array in the same say but, instead of concatenates (`+`) the values you override the previous value of text. at the end of the loop you only have the last value from the array and insert to the html